# How do I get a sortType for a field in an ExtJS store?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How do I get the sortType for a field in an ExtJS store?

This doesn't work:

```
var sortType = myStore.fields.get('MyFieldName').sortType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a string as sortType then it is converted to a function in the constructor of Ext.data.Field, so you need to compare that function with available sortTypes to get the correct sortType string

```
var sortTypeFn = myStore.fields.get('MyFieldName').sortType;
var sortType = '';
Ext.iterate(Ext.data.Types, function(key, obj) {
      if(obj.sortType == sortTypeFn) {
           sortType = key;
           return false;
      }
});
console.log(sortType);
```